# How to import native ios module to the react native project

Tags: objective-c, xcode, react-native, react-native-ios, native-module

I need to import MiSnapSDK module written in objective C to the react-native project. I have just a folder with source files - code, storyboard, frameworks, images and etc. Likely i need to create xcode project before i can link it to the main ios project. But i have no experience in ios development and don't now how to add all this files to the modules project.

I tried to add files to the project and install it form repository and link to the main project with command 'react-native link ' but only .h and .m files seem to work (only root files, event cant import files from sub-directories)

There is how source files look:
[image]